# Kustomize: Override values in dependency charts

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, kustomize

I'm wondering about the way to override a default value for a dependency chart.

Let's go straight to the point, having this kustomization file for Prometheus:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
helmCharts:
- name: prometheus
  releaseName: prometheus
  repo: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
  version: 23.0.0
  namespace: monitoring
```

I want to define for example the `storageClass` value for the alermanager chart which is a dependency of Prometheus chart. This is the folder structure created when try to build the chart.

```
.
├── charts
│   ├── prometheus
│   │   ├── Chart.lock
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── charts
│   │   │   ├── alertmanager
│   │   │   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── README.md
│   │   │   │   ├── ci
│   │   │   │   │   └── config-reload-values.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   │   │   ├── NOTES.txt
│   │   │   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   │   │   │   ├── configmap.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   ├── ingress.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   ├── services.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   ├── statefulset.yaml
│   │   │   │   │   └── tests
│   │   │   │   │       └── test-connection.yaml
│   │   │   │   ├── values.schema.json
│   │   │   │   └── values.yaml                               <-- Override a value here
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── NOTES.txt
│   │   │   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   │   │   ├── clusterrole.yaml
│   │   │   ├── clusterrolebinding.yaml
│   │   │   ├── cm.yaml
│   │   │   ├── deploy.yaml
│   │   │   ├── extra-manifests.yaml
│   │   │   ├── headless-svc.yaml
│   │   │   ├── ingress.yaml
│   │   │   ├── network-policy.yaml
│   │   │   ├── pdb.yaml
│   │   │   ├── psp.yaml
│   │   │   ├── pvc.yaml
│   │   │   ├── rolebinding.yaml
│   │   │   ├── service.yaml
│   │   │   ├── serviceaccount.yaml
│   │   │   ├── sts.yaml
│   │   │   └── vpa.yaml
│   │   ├── values.schema.json
│   │   └── values.yaml
│   └── prometheus-23.0.0.tgz
└── kustomization.yaml
```

**Question:**

How can I override a value in a dependency chart using Kustomize?

Comment: With Kustomize, you patch specific Kubernetes resources. What resource generated by the chart do you want to patch? The only resource I see for which a storageClass would make sense is a PersistentVolumeClaim that is part of the prometheus chart, not alertmanager.

Comment: I can patch for example the volumeClaimTemplate for the alertmanager StatefulSet for example, but the generation of another resources in some dependecy charts depends from the property value in the values.yaml file for that chart.

Answer (score 2):

You can define Helm values in Kustomize either inline or via files. These values will override the default ones of the Helm chart as you'd do with Helm outside Kustomize.

```yaml
helmCharts:
- name: prometheus
  releaseName: prometheus
  repo: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
  version: 23.0.0
  namespace: monitoring

  # Inline
  valuesInline:
    somekey: somevalue

  # Values files:
  valuesFile: values.yaml
  additionalValuesFiles:
  - values-file-1.yml
  - values-file-2.yml
```

[Documentation](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_helmchartinflationgenerator_)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is specific for the prometheus chart, but I was able to do this using a single kustomization values.yaml file like this:

```
imagePullSecrets:
 - name: "my-private-registry-secret"

configmapReload:
  prometheus:
    image:
      repository: my-private-registry/prometheus-operator/prometheus-config-reloader
      tag: v0.67.0
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

server:
  image:
    repository: my-private-registry/prometheus/prometheus
    # if not set appVersion field from Chart.yaml is used
    tag: ""
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  extraConfigmapMounts:
    - name: my-private-config-prometheus-scrapes
      mountPath: /etc/config/my-private-config-prometheus-scrapes/
      subPath: ""
      configMap: my-private-config-prometheus-scrapes
      readOnly: true
      
scrapeConfigFiles:
  - /etc/config/my-private-config-prometheus-scrapes/*.yaml

alertmanager:
  enabled: false

prometheus-pushgateway:
  enabled: false


#configs for a dependency chart:
prometheus-node-exporter:
  image:
    registry: my-private-registry
    repository: prometheus/node-exporter
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: "my-private-registry-secret"
```

And in the end, the deployment of the node-exporter was using my private registry for the image.

I tried this after looking the original values.yaml that came with the chart, and in it there was fields for kube-state-metrics, prometheus-node-exporter, and prometheus-pushgateway.